# How to import angular2-cookie in angular4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-cookie

I'm trying to import angular2-cookie in my angular4 project.

My project is built with angular-cli@1.2.7, here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "ng-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4201",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

the `angular2-cookie doc`https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie#cli ask me to add something in `angular-cli-build.js`, but I have neither `angular-cli-build.js` nor `systemjs.config.js`

I import `angular2-cookie` in `app.module.ts` with:

```
import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
...
...
providers: [
    CookieService
 ]
```

My project works well with `ng server` and it also works well in my chrome.

it is built successfully with `ng build --prod`, but when I run it in chrome or run it with `ng server --aot` , chrome console show this error:

```
ERROR Error: No provider for CookieOptions!
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks all!

Comment: This package is only for Angular 2, [as mentioned here](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/issues/54), you should use [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie)

Comment: Both angular2-cookie and ngx-cookie can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add CookieOptions in your import statement like import { CookieService, CookieOptions } from 'angular2-cookie'; and then add both CookieService and CookieOptions in your Root Module's provider array.